# Tracking Wordpress Statistics

Tags: wordpress, statistics, aggregate

I have a wordpress-based website (privately hosted, w/wordpress installed to the server, not a blog), which is serving as an online magazine. I would appreciate if the following is possible (and if so, how).

1. Tracking the number of posts that each user account made
2. The wordpress theme I am basing on allows for one to tweet, +1, and 'like'. Is it possible to see which authors are gaining the most social media shares through these websites?

Thanks in advance for what I know will be helpful answers.

Comment: Tracking how many posts each user has made is easy - the number is displayed in _Users -> All Users_. I'm not sure about the second requirement.

Comment: In fact, it's likely you'll need to get a custom plugin built to satisfy your second requirement. There's [a bunch of](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-stats-dashboard/) [social metrics](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-metrics/) plugins available, but none that I know of support per-author stats.